# Values not showing when hoovered around in gvisSankey plot

Tags: r, googlevis

I would like to know if we can display values on `gVissankey` plot.

For example for the below code

```
datSK <- data.frame(From=c(rep("A",3), rep("B", 3)),

To=c(rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"),2)),

Weight=c(5,7,6,2,9,4))

Sankey <- gvisSankey(datSK, from="From", to="To",    
                                    weight="Weight",
 options=list(

 sankey="{link: {color: { fill: '#d799ae' } },

 node: { color: { fill: '#a61d4c' },

 label: { color: '#871b47' } }}"))

plot(Sankey)
```

I would like the weight of the sankey say 5,7,6 being displayed when we move around the sankey plot.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working with googleVis:gvisSankey(). I re-ran your code and it actually showed the weight on mouseover (see attached screenshot).

Is it what you meant?

```
library(googleVis)

datSK <- data.frame(From = c(rep("A", 3),rep("B", 3)),
                    To = c(rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 2)),
                    Weight = c(5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 4))

Sankey <- gvisSankey(
  datSK, 
  from="From",
  to="To",
  weight="Weight",
  options=list(
    sankey="{link: {color: { fill: '#d799ae' } },
       node: { color: { fill: '#a61d4c' },
        label: { color: '#871b47' } }}"))

plot(Sankey)
```

[image: Sankey Plot]